# Injecting interfaces that have generics into Nancy Bootstrapper

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with a test of mine. Here is the test code:

```
    protected IAuditingService<BillingAudit> FakeBiometricsService;
    protected Browser Browser;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        FakeBiometricsService = A.Fake<IAuditingService<BillingAudit>>();
        A.CallTo(() => FakeBiometricsService.UpdateAudit(A<BiometricAudit[]>.Ignored)).DoesNothing();
        Browser = new Browser(c => c.Module<Biometrics>().Dependency(FakeBiometricsService));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void calling_endpoint_with_correct_data__calls_biometrics_service_to_save_data()
    {
        var response = Browser.Post("/Audits/Biometrics", with =>
                                                   {
                                                       with.HttpRequest();
                                                       with.Header("accept", "application/xml");
                                                       with.Body(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                                                           {
                                                               data = new[]
                                                                   {
                                                                       new
                                                                           {
                                                                               SomeProperty = SomeValue
                                                                           }
                                                                   }
                                                           }));
                                                   });
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        A.CallTo(() => FakeBiometricsService.UpdateAudit(A<BiometricAudit[]>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
```

So what I'm trying to do here is satisfy a constraint with my `A.Fake<IAuditingService<BillingAudit>>()`

Here's what that my modules look like. Every module extends this base class:

```
public abstract class AuditModuleBase<TModel, TService> : NancyModule  where TModel : BillingAudit, new() where TService : IAuditingService<TModel>, new()
{
    private readonly IAuditingService<TModel> _auditingService;

    protected AuditModuleBase(string endpoint, TService auditingService)
        : base("/Audits/" + endpoint)
    {
        _auditingService = auditingService;
        Post["/"] = x =>
        {
            var data = Request.Body.FromJson<JObject>();
            return SaveLocationUpdates(data["data"].Children().Select(y => (TModel)new TModel().Parse(y)).ToArray());
        };
    }

    private Response SaveLocationUpdates(TModel[] update)
    {
        _auditingService.UpdateAudit(update);
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

So, my biometrics module looks like this:

```
public class Biometrics : AuditModuleBase<BiometricAudit, BiometricsAuditingService>
{
    public Biometrics(BiometricsAuditingService service) : base("Biometrics", service) { }
}
```

Sorry for the code dump. The idea is that every module extends a base class that expects a T of type BillingAudit, and an IAuditingService. However, when I pass this fake into the dependency satisfier in the Browser object, Nancy looks up the actual implementation of IAuditingService> and passes that in, which is not the desired behaviour! Is there a problem with satisfying dependencies with FakeItEasy fakes? Or interfaces with generics? Or is it something really obvious I'm overlooking?

edit: Oh, I'd also like to mention that BiometricAudit extends BillingAudit. So it's an interface with a generic of an abstract class. I've tried faking an IAuditingService and an IAuditingService, but neither seems to satisfy Nancy.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it was less exciting than I thought. Sorry! I was just being silly.

I was trying to satisfy a dependency of type BiometricsAuditingService, which is a concrete implementation of IAuditingService. Once I changed that to be an interface, everything injected properly.